# HTML Padding Style

Tags: html, css

So I have this html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:20px">
        <h2>London</h2>
    </body> 
</html>
```

My question is, what does the `padding:20px` property do in the style attribute for the `div` element? Is that the same thing as doing `padding:top=20px`, `padding:right=20px`, `padding:bottom=20px`, `padding:left=20px`?

I tried putting (`padding:top=20px`, `padding:right=20px`, `padding:bottom=20px`, `padding:left=20px`) in the `h2` element as an attribute like this (removed `padding:20px` from the style attribute in the `div` element):

```
<h2 padding:top=20px, padding:right=20px, padding:bottom=20px, padding:left=20px>London</h2>
```

But for some reason the line above gave me a different output than putting the `padding:20px` in the style attribute of the `div` element. Can someone please explain me this difference? Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your syntax is full of errors.

It has to be

```
<h2 style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-left: 20px">London</h2>
```

and yes, in short this is identical to

```
<h2 style="padding: 20px">London</h2>
```

There is also three other short forms:

```css
/* applies 10px top/bottom, and 5px left/right */
padding: 10px 5px;
```

```css
/* applies 10px top, 0 to bottom, and 5px left/right */
padding: 10px 5px 0;
```

```css
/* applies 1px top, 2px right, 0 bottom, 4px left (clockwise, starting at top) */
padding: 1px 2px 0 4px;
```

Comment: This was an extremely helpful answer. Understanding the other forms of the padding attribute really helped me out. Thank you so much for explaining those as well! Also one quick question... Is style an attribute of the h2 html element or is it just a CSS attribute?

Comment: It's a so-called universal attribute which basically means that it is available on all HTML elements. Nonetheless it's widely considered bad practice to make use of it except in some very special cases where css properties (like for example background-image) must be set dynamically. The regular way to do it is to put your styles in a css class in your css stylesheet and then apply that to your elements via the (again) universal `class` attribute.

Comment: Ok! That makes complete sense now. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @connext: There is no need for semicolon after the  '`padding-left: 20px` ?

Comment: @aerijman In a CSS declaration block, the `;` after the last declaration may be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

not valid

```
<h2 padding:top=20px, padding:right=20px, padding:bottom=20px, padding:left=20px>London</h2>
```

use

```css
h2{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-left:20px">London</h2>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/3r36fm3o/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Dmitriy! I understand my mistake now!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `padding:20px;` applies the same amount of padding to all sides of your element.

Also, your HTML is incorrect. Do this:

```
<h2 style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-left:20px">London</h2>
```

Or simply,

```
<h2 style="padding:20px">London</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

yours, `h2` padding style is incorrect.

you should add `style` for the h2 element.

```
<h2 style="padding:20px">London</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna apply padding to all sides simultaneously, you're better off just using `padding:20px` as a value for style since it cuts down on code size.

See this link for more examples on the use of CSS padding:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Answer (score 0):

try this. you will know how the padding works. padding  is for positioning the text/element in an element(parent)

```html
 <div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:20px">
    
    <h2 style="border: solid 1px red">London</h2>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is totally wrong.It would be

```
    <h2 style="padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; padding-bottom: 20px; 
padding-left: 20px">London</h2>
```

Also if you want to give padding to all sides you can use as below :

```
<h2 style="padding: 20px;">London</h2>
```

Or you can also write like `padding:10px 20px 30px 40px;` it means `padding-top:10px,padding-right:20px,padding-bottom:30px,padding-left:40px,`

`Padding: 10px 20px` it means `padding-top:10px,padding-bottom:10px,padding-left:20px,padding-right:20px`

`Padding: 10px 30px 20px` it means `padding-top:10px,padding-bottom:20px,padding-left:30px,padding-right:30px`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Chandresh! I understand my mistake now!

Comment: Thanks for the edit Saina! Helped out a lot to know the different forms.

Answer (score 0):

`Padding:20px` will apply padding in all 4 directions .

You can also write this way `padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;` this goes like this  `padding : top right bottom left`

SO instead or write padding-right, padding-top and other two, one can simply write padding and apply the right left top bottom padding value to it. This method is helpful when we want to apply different padding values for all directions. Like `padding: 5px 10px;` This will apply padding 5px in top and bottom and 10px from left right;

Also, your HTML is incorrect. Do this:

```
<h2 style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-left:20px">London</h2>
```

OR

```
<h2 style="padding:20px 20px 20px 20px;">London</h2>
```

Or simply,

```
<h2 style="padding:20px;">London</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css syntax is incorrect

The correct syntax is:

```
<h2 style="padding-top=20px; padding-right=20px; padding-bottom=20px; padding-left=20px;">London</h2>
```

OR

```
<h2 style="padding=20px;">London</h2>
```

OR

```
<h2 style="padding=20px 20px 20px 20px;">London</h2>
```

Comment: Seems like you have to use : instead of = inside a string.
You do need = between attribute and value, since that is HTML and XML syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
h2{ padding:20px;}`<h2 style="padding:20px">London</h2>`
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
h2{
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h2 style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-left:20px">London</h2>
```

Answer (score -1):

padding:20px means you give 20px padding from top right bottom left. Do you mean padding-top, padding-right.... rather than the padding:right, padding:top etc.. cos this one is not working on mine.